# APEX wwv_flow_plugin.ajax_callback: ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, blob, oracle-apex

I exported my application and all database objects from a workspace hosted with a oracle apex hosting provider to my workspace which is hosted in a local server where I have installed OracleXE11g with APEX 4.2 (latest version).

Now in this application I have a table which contains BLOB data. I am trying to display these in a apex page using Region Attributes

The images are correctly displayed in "oracle apex hosting provider" apex application.
But the same is not working in "my local server" apex application.

I clicked the image location and selected "View Image" (Firefox -> right click on the image location & select this shortcut menu). It immediately saved my image as "download.FILE". I opened this notepad & found the error

wwv_flow_plugin.ajax_callback: ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified

I googled & found the following possible reasons provided almost in every post

ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified

Cause: There are several causes: (1) the LOB locator was never initialized; (2) the locator is for a BFILE and the routine expects a BLOB/CLOB/NCLOB locator; (3) the locator is for a BLOB/CLOB/NCLOB and the routine expects a BFILE locator; (4) trying to update the LOB in a trigger body -- LOBs in trigger bodies are read only.

Action: For (1), initialize the LOB locator by selecting into the locator variable or by setting the LOB locator to empty. For (2) and (3), pass the correct type of locator into the routine. For (4), remove the trigger body code that updates the LOB value.

Now I have just exported & imported this. When I execute an SQL command as
SELECT * FROM MY_BLOB_DATA_TABLE
the results are the same in both workspaces. So I am not going wrong here.

I wonder if there are any permissions I am missing

So, I went to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21673/otn_install.htm#BEHHJJIH and executed the script the enable permissions.

But still images are not displayed.

Please note that I am not using any procedure call to display images. It is simply configured in RegionAttributes section / tab.

I have no idea how to proceed now.

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND THE SOLUTION TO THIS ISSUE**
Let me go back to my error: ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified

**What I did?**
Moved the table with BLOB data from one workspace to another. A very important point to note here is that the actual BLOB object is not being moved here. So, with the content in my table, it is not able to locate my BLOB in database.

**What is the solution?**
This is not the right solution. If someone has a clean way on how to move BLOB data from one database to another, pls let know. Now coming back to what I did..
I reloaded my table with BLOB data in my apex server database again. So, this fixed the locator issues becoz it is considered as new insert.